# Azure notifications hubs in api net.core 1.1

Tags: push-notification, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-notificationhub

I'm looking for the entire network and I can not find anything clear.
I would like to know if it is possible to send notifications with the azure client in an api rest created with net.core 1.1.
The notifications of their own should reach the platforms configured in azure portal.

I explain my structure.
1. I have a backen (api) created with net.core 1.1, published in azure which maintains a database.
2. I have a croos-platform application, which I want to get the notifications sent from the api.

Say this with an asp.net api if  works, but create my new api an net.core and from here I am not able to install any azure client that can send the notifications. (Nuget Microsoft.Azure.notificationHub is not complatible With net.core)
`Package Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.8 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.8 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.`

Does anyone know an example or a small guide where you can do this ???

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you very much for your response.
But if you looked good, what I wanted was to use Azure.notificationsHub in my net.core project.

In the end I have achieved it in the following way.

In my file project.json 
The first thing to change is the framework, which has to be the following way.
**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Now it is possible to work with any nuget package in your net.core project, among others Azure.notificationsHub

[image]

Once this is done, you only have to create a method to send notifications

[image]

I hope it will help anyone who has the same problem. I tested and working perfectly.
Regards.

Comment: I'm trying to use the API from a core test project. it's saying it can't find System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.

Comment: i apologize, but this is saying "dependency error using framework version x can be solved by switching to framework y"; it's hard not to downvote

Answer (score 1):

As [Microsoft Azure Notification Hubs 1.0.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs) noted that:

> Please note that this package requires .Net Framework 4.5 Full Profile.

I found a feedback about [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs add support for .NET CORE](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs/suggestions/16417780-microsoft-azure-notificationhubs-add-support-for). I assumed that you could generate the authorization token and directly access the APIs from [Notification Hubs REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223264.aspx) for a workaround to achieve your purpose. And here is a git sample about [azure-notifications Send REST](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/dotnet/SendRestExample), you could refer to it for implementing the notification service in your .Net Core Web API project.